# Using Angular 2 Observable Data

Tags: angular, observable

I am very new to Angular 2 and trying to understand the basic structure I need to be using in my application. I have the code written to do an http get request on a PHP script which returns some JSON data from my database. This is written as an observable that I have subscribed to and can display the values in the template just fine. However, once this data finishes downloading (or as it's downloading?) I need to extract a UNIQUE value from each element of the JSON array and use that value in the query string on another http get. Think stock symbol stored in the database and then run a second get to retrieve the stock data from a REST service. The stock symbol may be repeated many times so I only want to perform the second http get request on each UNIQUE value (e.g. only get MSFT once from the REST service).

The data returned from each of these stock data gets needs to be looped over to extract specific data values, some of which will be used exactly as-is while others will be used in a calculation, the result of which gets displayed.

How do I structure the code to accomplish these extra calculations?

My code currently looks like this (obviously the console.log is for debugging purposes):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._tradeService.getTradeData()  // get database data
        .subscribe(
          res => this.mspTradeData = res,
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log(this.mspTradeData)
        );

    // TODO
    // get unique symbols for REST service queries
}
```

Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _The stock symbol may be repeated many times so I only want to perform the second http get request on each UNIQUE value (e.g. only get MSFT once from the REST service)._ what does this mean . a rest call will return only pone value or array of values what is the structure. Because this a case where you use [flatMap](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Comment: You can do something like this: this.tradeService.getTradeData().subscribe(res => { this.data = res; this.data.forEach(x => { this.tradeService.anotherFunction(x.property).subscribe()}), error...

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively advanced RxJs issue, involving a few operators, but I'll try to explain it simply.

If I understand correctly, the steps that you are looking for are:

1. Make a service call that returns an Observable of an array - let's call the type in the array 'TradeData', so the service returns `Observable<TradeData[]>`
2. Convert the single emitted array of TradeData into a stream of TradeData items.
3. Extract the stock symbols from the stream of TradeData items
4. Get a unique set of stock symbols from the previous step
5. Make a service call for each of the unique stock symbols
6. Collect all of the results from the calls in step 4 in one place.

This would look something like:

```
this._tradeService.getTradeData() // 1. make the api call
  .concatAll() // 2. convert stream of single item to stream of items
  .map(tradeDatum => tradeDatum.stockSymbol) // 3. extract the stock symbols
  .distinct() // 4. filter the stock symbols to a unique list
  .flatMap(stockSymbol => getStockData(stockSymbol) // 5. get the data for each stock symbol
  .toArray() // 6. collect the stream items into an array
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

Note that a major advantage over simply subscribing to the initial call and then making a service call for each item is that you get the entire result in one place, and you can also handle all errors in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've implemented these suggestions but I still have an issue. My Observable getTradeData is returning an Observable<any> which doesn't have a .concatAll() method available. I haven't figured out how to make my getTradeData method return a TradeData[] stream. Can you clarify how this is done?

Comment: Assuming that you're making an HTTP call, all you really need to do is specify the return type of the `getTradeData` function. You can also annotate the return type of the http call itself, for example, 

`this.http.get<TradeData[]>('http://service')`